# Authentication with firebase on unity: How to identify users with phone id

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I am currently working on my first mobile game with unity. I set up a db with Firebase and now I want to authenticate users with Firebase Authentication. In the documentation I found how to make it with Apple, Google, Facebook etc ... but nothing about how to make it with device ID.

Someone know how I can manage it ?

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceUniqueIdentifier.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for "AnonymousAuthentication". Note that this isn't based on device id, but rather installation instance (that is that uninstalling/reinstalling the game will reset the user as well as signing in twice).

Minimally modified from the [getting started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/anonymous-auth):

```
FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
  if (task.IsCanceled) {
    Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync was canceled.");
    return;
  }
  if (task.IsFaulted) {
    Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
    return;
  }

  Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
  Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
      newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
});
```

As I inferred before, every time you call `SignInAnonymouslyAsync`, you get a new user. The auth SDK does persist the user credentials between runs for you, so you can add a check like this:

```
if (_firebaseAuth.CurrentUser == null)
{
    // launch the sign in flow here
}
else
{
    // user is signed in, continue to your game
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think is even better than using device id (in case of owner change for exemple)